# Timetable for buses in Haute Nendaz (Switzerland)

Tags: buses, switzerland

I'm planning a trip to Haute Nendaz next winter and looking at some accommodation options, some of which is bus ride away from the ski lift. As part of this I was hoping to find a timetable but have been unable to - the routes are described at: https://www.nendaz.ch/en/free-shuttle-buses-fp44533.html for the winter season but clicking the times link takes you to a page for the summer season. The buses don't appear on Google maps and the page is not indexed in the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/).

Is there any other source of the bus times? I accept the exact times for the next winter season may not be known yet, but even a timetable from previous winter seasons would be a huge help - my experience from previous trips as that from one winter season to the next most changes are very minor and except the risk. But that changes between the summer and winter season can be very significant.

Comment: Might be easier to contact [Nendaz Tourisme](https://www.nendaz.ch/en/index.htm) by email (info@nendaz.ch) and ask for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find all the timetables for the shuttle bus in winter. But I found this page for the shuttle between [Nendaz and Siviez](https://nendaz.ch/fr/fppoi-bus-navette-haute-nendaz-siviez-44406.html). There is buses almost every 30 minutes, except for a pause at the time of lunch.
On [this other page](http://just-nendaz.com/the-village/getting-around/?lang=fr) (with lot of errors), other shuttle buses are described as running every 15 or 20 minutes.

My experience is that those kind of buses does not really follow a strict timetable, like other public transportations in Switzerland. They are only running just before the opening of the ski domain and just after they closed (9:00 - 16:30). Depending on the people they have to transport, they won't stop at the end of the loop and wait for the next slot, but will directly go and take the next persons.

Actually I'm wondering, why do you want to know the timetables? I think the routes are more important if you want to choose a hotel or rent a room where you don't have to walk too much.

Comment: Thank you, the primary reason I wanted a timetable was to find out the frequency of the routes, although yes the distance to the stops is important I think that the frequency is as well - I don't mind staying along one of them if it comes along every 15min but I wouldn't want to be waiting around for an hourly bus. Interesting that your experience with a lack of timetables though, I can't say I've noticed the same (and other 4 valleys areas have one). Still thank you for the every 15-20min source and I'm going to take up nohillside suggestion of the tourist office.